# Solspace Super Search - Results relationship field

Tags: solspace, relationships

I have Super Search installed and running on my Expression Engine v2.8.1 install the search functionality is working fine except for when it returns the results the relationship field does not display the relevant information it return the field tag instead `{state}`. is there something that i am missing when it comes to displaying relationship field in the results?

```
{exp:super_search:results orderby="date" paginate="bottom" limit="4" channel="properties"}
    <p>{state:abbreviation}</p>
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Which version of EECMS are you using on this site?

Comment: ExpressionEngine v2.8.1

Comment: Please, show us the part of the template where this relationship field is. Thanks!

Comment: Example: `{exp:super_search:results orderby="date" paginate="bottom" limit="4" channel="properties"}<p>{state:abbreviation}</p>{/exp:super_search:results}`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the following?:

`{state}<p>{state:abbreviation}</p>{/state}`

Comment: Does this relationship field allow the user to choose one or multiple options?